# querySelectorAll stopped returning element objects

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

This code was working...

```
    selectItem = (targetId, listId) => {
        let listItems = this.template.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

        for(let item of listItems) {
            if(item.dataset.id === targetId) {
                item.classList.add('selected');
            }
            else {
                item.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
    }
```

But now it seems to just return this

```
{\"$$OwnerKey$$\":11}
```

template...

```
<template for:each={t.vals} for:item="val">
    <div key={val.valId} id={val.valId} class="slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_x-large list-item" onclick={handleListClick}>
        <div>{val.title}</div>
    </div>    
</template>
```

javascript...

```
    handleListClick = (event) => {
        if(this.thisName.includes(this.debugTarget)) {
            console.log('bw: handleListClick');
        }
        let targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
        this.selectItem(targetId);
    }
```

No errors but obviously that data will not pass the conditions in the loop.  Any Ideas?

Comment: What instance is your org on? Also, can you share a bit more of your template code?

Comment: Mohith, I have added the pertinent template code, I am not sure what you mean by instance, the org is a developer sandbox.

Comment: This is still not complete, how is the selectItem method called?

Comment: Sorry Mohith, I updated the post with the code.

Comment: Check the code I have in the answer to see if that helps!! Also your method seems to take two parameters while you pass only one?

Comment: Try not to use the id attribute to store any custom identifier in the LWC framework. Sometimes it throws unexpected results. Use dataset instead. 
Use <div key={val.valId} data-id={val.valId}... -> to assign custom identifier &
Use event.currentTarget.dataset.id -> to read the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code to pass the data in to the component for setting the css class needed to render the object instead of trying to update the template using the querySelector.

So instead of this

```
let listItems = this.template.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
item.classList.add('selected');
```

the payload object to the component was changed to this

```
listItem.selected = true;
get itemClass() {
   return (this.listItem.selected ? "list-item selected" : "list-item");
}

//template
<div class={itemClass}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine. You can see the code in action [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/zGvIVFg9uFbDieO0Iaim)

```
<template>
  <template for:each={t.vals} for:item="val">
    <div key={val.valId} id={val.valId} data-id={val.valId} class="slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_x-large list-item"
        onclick={handleListClick}>
        <div>{val.title}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

The controller code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  @track 
   t = {
     vals:  [
    {

      "valId" : 1,
      "title" : 'test'
    },
     {

      "valId" : 2,
      "title" : 'test2'
    },
    {

      "valId" : 3,
      "title" : 'test3'
      }
   ]
 }

 handleListClick (event) {
    let listItems = this.template.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

    for(let item of listItems) {
        if(item.dataset.id === event.currentTarget.dataset.id) {
            item.classList.add('selected');
        }
        else {
            item.classList.remove('selected');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I added a bit of CSS to see it working

```
.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: That did not work for me, just got back OwnerId, ultimately I just refactored the code to push the class into the component with the object and used that to render what I needed.  Probably the more acceptable way to do it any way.  Thanks for your help though!